# How to remove incorrectly formatted text data in Google Data Studio?

Tags: looker-studio

**I am exstracting Text format data from Firebase and I want to show only correctly formatted data in LookerStudio.**

Now the text data looks like this,

| No. | Sample_Date |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | AAA 1/2(M) |
| 2 | AAA 1/17(T) |
| 3 | AAA 12/7(W) |
| 4 | AAA M 21/2 |
| 5 | AAA W 23/2 |
| 6 | AAA T, 21/2 |
| 7 | AAA W 21.2. |
| 8 | AAA M 27-2 |
| 9 | AAA 2.21. (T) |
| 10 | AAA 2/21T |

Data such as No.1-3 "AAA MM/DD(D)" is the correct format.
Other format such as No.4-10 is incorrect formtat, and I want to remove them from the report.

**What I tried:**

I have tried to extract correct data that contains "/" and "()" using RegEx, but this cannot extract "()" correctly.

```
CASE
 WHEN REGEXP_CONTAINS(Sample_Date, "AAA") AND WHEN REGEXP_CONTAINS(Sample_Date, "/") AND WHEN REGEXP_CONTAINS(Sample_Date, "(.)") THEN "Correct Data"
ELSE "Other"
END
```

Here is [Publicly editable sample data of Looker Studio](https://lookerstudio.google.com/reporting/cc10b60e-7c44-4c0e-81b8-1c63e5f68cb7).

Any advice would be helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Added regex expression to your [dash here](https://lookerstudio.google.com/u/0/reporting/cc10b60e-7c44-4c0e-81b8-1c63e5f68cb7/page/p_yny647cs3c/edit):

```
REGEXP_MATCH(Sample_Date,"[A-Z]{3} \\d+/\\d+\\(.\\)")
```

[image]